# How to fix "iterable expected, not int" when using csv.writerow?

Tags: python, csv

I want to write to a CSV file the first index from the 1st and 2nd array.

Every time I've got

> iterable expected, not int.

```
import csv
xd = [1,2,3,4,5]
dx = [5,4,3,2,1]
data = xd, dx
with open("houses.csv", "w", newline="") as p:
    cmon = csv.write(p, delimiter=",")
    for x in len(xd):
        yo = data[0][x], data[1][x]
        yo2 = list(yo)
        cmon.writerows(yo2)
```

Comment: `len(xd)` -> `range(len(xd))`

Comment: `len(xd)` will return an `int` not an iterable

Answer (score 0):

As @Ghilas BELHADJ pointed out, you are iterating over an integer:

In this line:

```
for x in len(xd):
```

len(x) returns the length/count of x. To iterate over it call:

```
for x in range(len(x)):
```

This creates a list [0,..., len(x)-1] and then you iterate over it to get the indexes.